# VPN and posts on forums

Tags: vpn

I know that VPN changes my IP that is seen by websites but I wonder about topics and posts sent to them.

Does VPN change IP of the post/topic (IP from which the post/topic was sent) or it will appear as my real one?

Comment: Why do you think that the VPN would work to "visit" but not the "post"? Are they not the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

A VPN encrypts your traffic between you and the VPN provider. The traffic appears as if it is originating at the VPN provider.

With that said, there's many other ways to identify someone other than their IP.

- Cookies set in the browser
- User agent
- Various other fingerprinting (canvas, resize, visited links, flash, Java, webrtc, location API, etc.)

If you're attempting to post anonymously on a forum you're banned from it may evade a IP ban, but you could be identified from other logged information (most likely would be a full user agent match since those are saved on most server logs by default)

Comment: That is not always true. It would depend on whether the VPN is forcing all routes through it (commonly called "tunnel all") or only routing specific traffic through it (commonly called "split-tunnel").  For example, you can route a specific public IP address for a website through VPN, and make that traffic come from the IP address of the VPN provider, while leaving the rest of the internet-bound traffic to route directly through the customer/client's own ISP and appear as whatever IP address that provider is assigning to the customer.

Comment: @JesseP. That's a good point. In addition to that, some clients can selectively tunnel a specific subset of apps (OpenVPN on Android). The most common configurations used by the general public operate in a "tunnel all" configuration.